# JQuery is not loading in an iframe in IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have two different web applications in different domains. in `web app1`, i have an iframe and its src refers a page which is in `web app2`.The page which needs to be loaded in an iframe has some JQuery.But the problem is it is not loading in an iframe. But if i access the same page in the same web app2 then it is working fine. `It works fine in Fire fox and the issue is only with IE. am using IE7.`

I have below code in the page which needs to be rendered in an iframe.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Am i doing anything wrong here? Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using IE7 when more modern browsers exist?

Comment: it does not work even in IE8+ browsers

Comment: Could you post your code of where you have your iframe?

Comment: @Chad..Theyare internal sites...

Comment: Main issue is both the applications are on different domains..

Comment: download the jquery script and put it on your site. then include it from there instead of from google.

Answer (score 0):

IE can have issues with security when using IFrames.

Try setting your security mode to lowest for that site and see if it works (**Making sure to set it back after testing to ensure your browser isn't left vulnerable!**). If it does, change the code in the iframe to load the javascript from the same domain instead of the CDN. (or just try this first!)

It is possible that IE is preventing the content of the iframe from loading the JS from a seperate domain. You can check this using something like fiddler, see what calls the page makes after loading.

Comment: where can i set the security mode to lowest? Thanks!

Comment: @user1016403 I only have IE9, but in there it is Internet Options -> Security, or Internet Options -> Privacy. Just remember to set it back to what it's currently on otherwise your browser might be vulnerable.

Comment: i need to change the browser settings in the system where i have an iframe but not in the system where i have the page that needs to be displayed in an iframe right? Thanks!

Comment: Change the browser settings on your PC that you are browsing from.